# Loading between Activitys instead of Blackscreen

Tags: android, performance

Is it possible to do a Loading Screen/Dialog to Activity during loading?. 
All my pages are single class. This feels a little unperformant. 
My attempt to use a load dialog. 
This is the onCreate of my Activity.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);
onFill(name);
dialog.cancel();
```

This does not work :( 
My Intent for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(main_list.this, settings.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Also, you should use `finish()` instead of `System.exit();`

Comment: why `System.exit(0);` ? this will kill your application.

Comment: there is no loading dialog just a black screen until the activity is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `onCreate` of `MyActivity`

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run()
  {

    //do here your work i.e. call onFill(name);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    });
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: Need i special rights? I get this Error MyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: MyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView

Comment: Also i get "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `cancel()` on your `ProgressDialog` after showing it

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
            "Loading. Please wait...", true);
onFill(name);
dialog.cancel();
```

I don't know what `onFill(name)` does but maybe you want to put the cancel call in that method which means you will want to make your `ProgressDialog` a member variable or just put the call to `show()` inside that method as well.